# Stereo Rectification to specific angle

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration

cv::stereoRectify will rectify 2 cameras by moving only one of the camera. What I want to achieve is, say I have a image of calibration board, and rectify "both" camera so that they confront to the board. Can anyone give clues to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

cv::stereoRectify does not "move" any cameras.

Rather, it projects (i.e. warps) both images onto a specially chosen plane in such a way that corresponding epipolar lines end up mapped on the same image rows. This greatly simplifies (and robustifies) the search for correspondences in stereo matching.

Comment: It was my misunderstanding. So stereoRectify will "rotate" 2 cameras so that both camera are placed on the same image plane.
Thus I cannot use stereoRectify achieve my goal. Can you give anyone clues to achieve my goal, which is to "move" both camera so that the rectified image plane confront (≒are parallel) to the certain object?